# How do you minimize cake doming?

Tags: baking, cake

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a cake lift equally?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/how-to-make-a-cake-lift-equally)

I'm working on a layer cake for a birthday and did a test run today since I really have no experience with baking cakes. I had some severe doming issues - I'm actually not sure if the cake rose at all on the sides from where the batter was when it was initially poured into the (9" round dark nonstick metal) pan.

As this is a layer cake I really need a flat cake - what can I do to eliminate or at least minimize doming?

I'm aware that I can cut the dome off but I'm trying to minimize the amount of shaping that needs to be done.

Comment: This was answered well very recently: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/how-to-make-a-cake-lift-equally

Comment: I would just suggest that the previous question have its title modified as it is not really searchable as-is (which is why I ended up asking it again - because I couldn't find it in a search before asking).