# How to keep the surface of the cake from splitting?

Tags: baking, cake

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you make a cake lift equally and minimize doming?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/how-do-you-make-a-cake-lift-equally-and-minimize-doming)

[image]

Or is it natural for it to happen because the top layer has expanded? what should I do if I wanted to make an even-surfaced cake? Not convex shaped as you can see in the photo? Should I cover the tin with an aluminium foil?

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate! thanks for pointing me there. I guess I got my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have read and heard that to minimize the cracks you should tilt the batter back and forth in the pan prior to baking. If you let the batter climb the walls about 1/8" - 1/4" it supposedly helps with not only a consistent rise, but keeps the batter from clinging to the wall while rising and stretching the surface of your cake while it rises.

I have done this with white cakes since I began baking a few months back in a springform and had good results, however I have never not done it.