# using icing with buttercream to write with

Tags: meringue

I am decorating a cookie for a wedding and packing them separate in a clear bag for a thank you gift.  I've used the instructions from the meringue container for icing but wanted to know if I could use butter cream with real butter, add the meringue powder and have crust up so the writing doesn't smear in the package but taste better than plain icing.

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32007/what-does-meringue-powder-do-in-butter-cream-icing)? The comments and answers do address how it behaves, although the question is a bit different than yours..

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest using buttercream icing- even if you add meringue powder to it, I don't think it will get as hard as you'll need it to prevent it from being ruined when put inside the bags. I always use royal icing with meringue for my icing ([this recipe](https://www.dominosugar.com/recipe/royal-icing-meringue-powder), specifically) and I think it tastes great.