# How can I attach printed rice paper decorations to cakes / cookies?

Tags: baking, icing, decorating, frosting

I bought some printed rice paper decorations (flat circles of rice paper printed with edible ink) for my son's birthday party. I'm not sure what the best way is to attach them to cakes / cookies and I don't have a lot of spare time to experiement.

The options I can think of are:

- make my own cookies and press them in to the cookie - either before
  baking or more likely after baking but while still warm and soft
- place the rice paper circle on top of a pre-baked cookie or small flat-topped cake and pipe some form of icing or frosting around the
  edge to hold it in place
- pile butter cream icing on top of a small cake, press the rice paper circle onto the butter cream icing

What I ideally want is to be able to do this the day before they are needed, so as well as being held properly in place, I also would like the rice paper not to go soggy / curl up and the ink not to run or leak out of the rice paper.

Comment: Will you use it with both cake and cookies? Depending on what exactly you are making, you can use a drop of water and the rice paper sticks (but it's possible this isn't a good solution for you).

Comment: I can do either cake or cookies, whichever is easier to make work or gives a better result.

Comment: @Mien, also, would the drop of water be at risk of making the ink run? I don't know what the ink is composed of.

Comment: Well, the drop of water method was a spectactular failure. I had a flat cake covered with fondant icing, I put a drop of water and pushed the rice paper down but it didn't stick at all. I tried a bit more water and the rice paper decoration started to go soggy and tear (but still didn't stick). With a new piece of rice paper I tried again, I thought I had got it OK using a very precise amount of water and very very careful handling, but when I came back to the cake 5 mins later the water and rice paper had dried and the rice paper had curled up and was not stuck to the cake at all.

Comment: Have you called the support line from the rice paper company, if they have one?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: N/A - I ordered them from an ebay seller and they came without any branded packaging, just in a plain plastic wallet.

Comment: Can you contact the seller and ask for advice? In particular, are you sure he used cake-decorating rice paper? There's more than one type of rice paper, and not all of them play well with frosting.

Comment: @Marti, I've just emailed the seller to ask. They are advertised as "cake toppers rice/wafer paper Edible" so I think they ought to stick OK *somehow*!

Comment: I also just found http://cakecentral.com/t/650730/how-do-i-apply-rice-wafer-paper which suggests Crisco, which I think is like Stork in the UK (vegetable shortening).

Comment: Isn't Stork margarine? Cookeen is a brand of vegetable shortening in the UK.

Comment: @Mien: Oh, I thought margarine == vegetable shortening. Thanks for that!

Comment: No, there is certainly a difference, margarine looks like butter, shortening does not (it's white and softer).

Comment: The ebay seller's recommendation was to use a little bit of water as well. I already know that doesn't work! I found another reference to suggest using gel icing, which I can imagine could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the buttercream option, let the icing dry a bit before putting the rice paper on, as too much moisture will cause it to collapse and the ink to run.  Also, I wouldn't recommend pressing the rice paper down, but just patting it onto slightly tacky buttercream.  White icing is best as the rice paper is quite translucent.

The other alternative you suggest will work fine - place it on the cake and pipe around the edge to hold in place.  I have seen this done many times.  Best not to use a vivid colour for the piping as it could leech into the rice paper a bit.

Answer (score 6):

When I've seen them used, they first frosted the cake, [smoothed it out](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/22277/67), then placeed the rice paper on top.

My understanding is that the moisture in the frosting can end up melting the rice paper, so that it basically disappears into the frosting, with the ink effectively transfering into the frosting.

As I've never done it myself, I have no idea if there are any special tricks to it, or if you need to use a particular frosting / icing recipe so that the paper will melt away.

**update:** after a little research, I have reason to believe that normal rice paper won't disolve into the cake but there are special 'frosting sheets' that will.  another recomendation was to leave enough white space around the image so that you can cover the edge of the sheet with a border if it starts to curl up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I wavered back and forth on whether to award the bounty to your answer or Phil M Jones' answer, in the end I picked his simply because his seemed to be more based on experience. I did appreciate your answer too, though!

Comment: @Vicky : not a problem.  When you first asked, I assumed that you needed it soon ... I typically prefer not to answer unless I have experience.  (my only knowledge of it was asking the bakery at Kroger questions when they first started offering it back in ~1998 or so, and then some internet searching)

Comment: I did need it soon, you were quite right! I ended up going with a completely different cake option and not using the toppers at all when it became clear that the "drop of water" idea wasn't going to work. I still have the toppers so I am planning to use them another time.

Answer (score 2):

I saw a decorating demo in "Everyday Living with Cheryl ???(can't remember her last name)" with potato starch paper printed.  The lady used dried royal icing on her cookies and applied corn syrup to back of design as paste and pressed onto decorated item.  Some piped decoration around edges helped hold down edges or press down as drying to adhere...She also had a printer with edible ink so she could print her own and used scrapbooking cutters for shapes

Answer (score 2):

I see you got no response about the fondant discs - use ready to roll fondant/ sugarpaste (different names depending where you live)and roll it out to about 3mm thick.  Using a round cutter, cut out some circles a fraction larger than your rice paper circles (or whatever shape they happen to be?). Place them on baking parchment or kitchen towel to dry out (pref overnight. White fondant is best. Then apply the prints to the icing using methods already discussed.  I've never used rice paper images as I prefer images printed to icing sheets as they're far superior but a bit more expensive.  They don't curl and the colours and print is more vibrant/clearer.  Icing images stick to fondant with a tiny amount of water.  Then pipe a swirl of buttercream on top of the cupcake, leave a few minutes to crust then pop the icing disc/image on top of the buttercream with a little pressure.  Hope that helps. Debs x

Answer (score 2):

A cake teacher taught me this method and it works beautifully.
Trace your image onto the rice paper (bumpy side up) with edible ink.
Cut the image out with about an 1/4 inch border left on. Place picture on cake.  Use a toothpick to outline the image.  Remove image and spread piping gel (get at Michaels, Hobby Lobby etc.) inside the traced toothpick lines.  Place the rice paper image on top of the piping gel. Spread another layer of piping gel over the image. Dilute your gel colors with water and paint the image with food grade paint brushes (so you don't get bristles on the cake!) Use a fine tip brush with black to outline. I remove the image before slicing the cake.

Answer (score 0):

You could try rolling out very thin gumpaste or fondant and attaching the rice paper on it when its moist but not wet. I haven't tried it myself but royal icing might be a good option to attach the paper to the surface. Once attached to the gumpaste, you can cut it out using a small knife and let it dry. Then it should be easier to attach the gumpaste cutout to the actual cake.

Answer (score -1):

I use rice paper discs a lot. I cut out rolled fondant circles, put edible glue on the fondant discs, then put the rice paper disc on top. Works a treat - just let them dry for a few days then use.

Comment: Maybe it's just because I don't do decorative baking much, but I'm confused - you're attaching the rice paper to fondant, not cakes and cookies.