# Why does my cake rise more in the center?

Tags: baking, cake

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you make a cake lift equally and minimize doming?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/how-do-you-make-a-cake-lift-equally-and-minimize-doming)

I recently started baking and my cakes always seem to rise more in the center, creating a sort of bump. It has never come out flat, though otherwise the cake seems to taste fine.

This happens with regular cakes and vegan cakes with no eggs/milk. Am I not pouring the mixture correctly or is it something to do with my oven?

This causes a problem when I try to make layer cakes or some decorative frosting as the cake is convex rather than flat.

Comment: Interesting - so far I only encountered cakes that don't rise enough in the center because the form gets too hot so the edges of the cake bake much faster then the middle. So maybe it's the other way around for you because you have a heatspot in the middle of your oven. What forms do you use? What type of oven do you use? What settings on the oven do you use?