# How can I make my almond buns rise evenly?

Tags: bread, almonds, rising

I make small almond flour buns using silicone molds shaped like half a ball, my problem is that I need them to rise evenly so that I can get a perfect mini-bun shape.
What should I do?

Comment: We need a _lot_ more information before we can attempt to answer this. What is the recipe? How are you cooking it?

Comment: mixi 6 eggs in a bowl, add 100 g melted butter and mix, add 150 g almond flour and 2 ts of baking powder and mix into a mostly lumpless mixture.
Pour about 1/3 cup into molds and bake for 20 min on 175 C.

Comment: Ok - and in what way do they rise unevenly? Do they dome?

Comment: they have a dome on the side, I want them to either have a dome on the center or better yet - not dome at all but rise evenly on all sides.

Comment: A picture of them in the mold would be helpful. Are they all domed toward the outside of the of the mold pan, are the domes all on the same side (like all on the left side of each bun when in the mold) or totally random with no pattern at all?

Comment: Now that I look at it it seems that they dome towards the sides of the mold pan, I guess it's because I didn't use the frame.

Comment: But even if do they dome perfectly - I would like to find a way to make them rise evenly so that in the end they'll look like mini burger buns.
My mold looks like this: http://goo.gl/iUPgp0
I would like the buns to look like this: http://goo.gl/2dStu8

Comment: Does the mold actually sit flat in your oven? Do you put it on a sheet pan or something? It's possible that the buns are rising straight up but your pan isn't flat, so when you pull them out of the oven, they're lopsided.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your mold may not be sitting totally flat in the oven. Try putting it in the oven on a baking sheet.

One way to minimize doming, is to lower your baking temperature. There is a lot of good information in this [answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/13170) to a similar question.